# Help : Add Bundle Product to Cart/Quote

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, bundle-product

I have been trying to `create an order` using a custom extension, I managed to do so, but whenever I try to add a `bundle product` I get a message error

> Selected required options are not available.

here is the code I'm using

```
<?php

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productDetails["product_id"]);

$optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();
$selectionCollection =$product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
$options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);

foreach($options as $option) {

    $_selections = $option->getSelections();

    foreach($_selections as $selection) {
        $bundled_items[$option->getOptionId()] = $selection->getSelectionId();
    }
}

$config = new Varien_Object(['product' =>$productDetails["product_id"],
                // X        'qty' => $productDetails["qty"],
                // 2        'bundle_options' => $bundled_items, 
                // array( 234 => 1070, 235=> 1646)
                            'bundle_option_qty' => $productDetails["bundle_option_qty"],
                // array( 234 => 2, 235=>2 )
                            ]);
$quote->addProduct($product, $config);

?>
```

I found out that when loading the bundle items I'm not getting the options and that's why I get the exception

I also tried to use `Magento's soap API` but ones again when trying to add a bundle I get the error message " `

> Please specify the product option(s).

**I've been stuck on this for 4days now, any help is very much appreciated and thank you**

Answer (score 0):

try below code may be this code will help you

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$productId = 10; //product id

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);

if($product->getTypeId() == "bundle"){

    $bundled_items = array();
    $optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();
    $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
    $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);

    foreach($options as $option) {
        $_selections = $option->getSelections();

        foreach($_selections as $selection) {
            $bundled_items[$option->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
    }

    $params = array('bundle_option' => $bundled_items,'qty' => 1,'product'=>$productId);
}

if (isset($params['qty'])) {
    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
        array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
        );
    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
}

$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load($productId);

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();

Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
    array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
);
```

Comment: I tried the code and I did a slit change ( since my options are not multi, I removed the counter and kept one selection for each option ). but still getting the same error. my problem is not about the params, I manage to get them correctly, but  **when I load the product I get empty options**, so when I pass it on addProduct, it reaches a point where **Magento tries to getOptions but it's empty and returns the error message**, to be specific it happens in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract._prepareOptions` when fetching `$this->getProduct($product)->getOptions()`

Comment: i have add another answer you can check

Answer (score 0):

To get All Options For Bundle Products you can use

```
$store_id = $_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
                $options = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Option')
             ->getResourceCollection()
                              ->setProductIdFilter($product->getId())
                              ->setPositionOrder();
             $options->joinValues($store_id);
    $typeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type');
    $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection($typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product), $product);
```

Comment: the thing is that I already get the options this way and I pass them as a parameter of addProduct but when loading the product itself the options are always an empty array and I don't wanna override Magento's functions. I get the error message `Selected required options are not available.` or I get `Please specify product option(s).`